# How to get response as json format(application/json) in yii?

Tags: php, yii

How to get response as json format(application/json) in yii?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### For Yii 1:

Create this function in your (base) Controller:

```
/**
 * Return data to browser as JSON and end application.
 * @param array $data
 */
protected function renderJSON($data)
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo CJSON::encode($data);

    foreach (Yii::app()->log->routes as $route) {
        if($route instanceof CWebLogRoute) {
            $route->enabled = false; // disable any weblogroutes
        }
    }
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Then simply call at the end of your action:

```
$this->renderJSON($yourData);
```

### For Yii 2:

[Yii 2 has this functionality built-in](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-responses#response-body), use the following code at the end of your controller action:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
return $data;
```

Comment: I have noticed that setting the **header()** or **Yii::app()->end();** does not make any difference. In Chrome Developer Tools, if you notice the **Response Header** under the **Header** tab, they all give the same Content-Length. If the ajax has been made with the output expected in the "json" format, then even if HTML is sent, the browser/jQuery treats that response as json. And it seems to work in all modern browsers. Though, I dont deny that setting the header() is a good thing.

Comment: Instead of disabling the web log routes, this approach will be more robust (not tested yet):

~~~
ob_start();
Yii::app()->end(0, false);
ob_end_clean();
exit(0);

Answer (score 20):

For Yii2 inside a controller:

```
public function actionSomeAjax() {
    $returnData = ['someData' => 'I am data', 'someAnotherData' => 'I am another data'];

    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $response->data = $returnData;

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. +1 for following Yii's api.

Comment: Thanks Mister! ^-^

Answer (score 19):

```
$this->layout=false;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo CJavaScript::jsonEncode($arr);
Yii::app()->end();
```

Comment: Also don't forget to disable WebLogRoutes before calling Yii::app()->end(), or debug info might get appended to your json and potentially render it invalid.

Comment: pretty sure that end() turns off the logs, which is why i added it here

Comment: It does not. end(): "Terminates the application. This method replaces PHP's exit() function by calling onEndRequest before exiting." And in CLogRouter (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogRouter#processLogs-detail): "This method is an event handler to the CApplication::onEndRequest event."

Comment: @marcovtwout, yes, you are right. I was thinking of exit() which ends the application before Yii can and hence no log.

Answer (score 10):

```
$this->layout=false;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
Yii::app()->end();
```

Comment: A few tewaks: use CJSON::encode() for models; no need to do `$this->layout=false` since `Yii::app()->end()` will terminate the app without outputting the layout.

Comment: I think is better you change the best answer to @marcovtwout

Answer (score 5):

```
class JsonController extends CController {

    protected $jsonData;

    protected function beforeAction($action) {
        ob_clean(); // clear output buffer to avoid rendering anything else
        header('Content-type: application/json'); // set content type header as json
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    protected function afterAction($action) {
        parent::afterAction($action);
        exit(json_encode($this->jsonData)); // exit with rendering json data
    }

}

class ApiController extends JsonController {

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->jsonData = array('test');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

one more simple way by using

```
echo CJSON::encode($result);
```

example code:

```
public function actionSearch(){
    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && isset($_POST['term'])) {
            $models = Model::model()->searchNames($_POST['term']);
            $result = array();
            foreach($models as $m){
                $result[] = array(
                        'name' => $m->name,
                        'id' => $m->id,
                );


            }
            echo CJSON::encode($result);
        }
}
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

for Yii2 use this simple to remember option

```
Yii::$app->response->format = "json";
return $data
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action that you want to render [JSON](http://yii.codexamples.com/v1.1/CJSON/) data, e.g: actionJson()

```
public function actionJson(){
    $this->layout=false;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo CJSON::encode($data);
    Yii::app()->end(); // equal to die() or exit() function
}
```

See more [Yii API](http://yii.codexamples.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
Yii::app()->end()
```

I think this solution is not the best way to end application flow, because it uses PHP's `exit()` function, witch means immediate exit from execution flow. Yes, there is Yii's `onEndRequest` handler, and PHP's `register_shutdown_function` but it still remains too fatalistic.

For me the better way is this

```
public function run($actionID) 
{
    try
    {
        return parent::run($actionID);
    }
    catch(FinishOutputException $e)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public function actionHello()
{
    $this->layout=false;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo CJavaScript::jsonEncode($arr);
    throw new FinishOutputException;
}
```

So, the application flow continues to execute even after.

Comment: If you already put layout=false, a simple 'return' will do? Can even be omitted. I see no reason to try/catch and create custom exception.

Comment: That's just bad.  Throwing an Exception to output the response.

Comment: Now, after some time I totally agree that using exceptions to manage controller/presentation logic is wrong.