# yii controller action won't fire from form

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm trying get a simple ajax call working with yii, not using the native yii means.  My goal is to populate  state and city fields on input from a zip code field, using a db look up in the create action. I have a separate javascript file,

```
    $('#Accounts_zip').bind('focusout',function(){     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
          url:'/gatesadmin/index.php?r=Accounts/Ziplookup',
          data: {zip:$('#Accounts_zip').val()},
          success:  function(datain, textStatus, jqXHR) {alert(datain.statecode);} ,
          error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorthrown){alert(errorthrown);},
          dataType:JSON
       });
    alert($('#Accounts_zip').val());
    });
```

and in my AccountsController I have:

```
public function actionZiplookup()
{
    $z = new ZipDao();
    $row = $z->GetCityStateByZip($_REQUEST['data']);
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"');
    echo CJSON::encode(array('output'=>$row));
}
```

and my form is out of the box generated CRUD:

```
...
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'zip'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'zip',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'zip'); ?>
</div>
...
```

I know the javascript is working because I get my alert, and if I call the URL directly  yii fires the actionZiplookup event because I'm getting the returned json.  I just can't seem to be able to get the form to invoke the ajax successfully because I get External Server error in the jquery ajax failure event.  I've combed through the net and the closest examples I can find embed the javascript in the form itself and use the Yii::app()-createUrl() method to define the url, but there has to be a way getting the controller action to fire while keeping javascript code in a separate file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the actual error you see in your failure alert?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I was missing can be found here: 
[How to get response as json format(application/json) in yii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824805/how-to-get-response-as-json-formatapplication-json-in-yii)  It all has to do with telling the controller to ignore the layout, etc.